# OOPs concepts into Javascript widget

Tags: javascript, oop

A simple javascript widget design question.
I have started working in javascript fairly recently. And as part of my work, I intend to create a lot of reusable code; so for me javascript widgets seems like the best way to go.
However I am faced with a design dilemma, and I am not able to find the right answer.

I have a simple javascript widget, which alters the string in a html component. So my widget is somewhat like this:

```
(function() {
    var convertString = function() {
         $(".classForHtmlComponentsIWantToHandle").each(function(index, element) {
             //js_fu stuff done with string fetched from "element"
         });
    };

    var _somePrivateHelperMethod() {
        //some work that would have been impossible without this helper method
    };

    GloballyDefinedNamespace.StringUtils = {convert : convertString};
}());
```

this allows me to call later

```
GloballyDefinedNamespace.StringUtils.convert();
```

Now if you would notice in my widget-ish function above, I extract all the HTML components from the DOM, that I want to alter string for. Interesting bit is that HTML will have span and divs with same css class and also textbox components with css class.

Both have a different way of extracting their value and setting new value back. 
Based on my experience, if this is a widget to alter string then all it should care about is incoming object that "hold" string in a uniform manner and then based on a object expectations, my widget should be able to operate blindly.

"if it sounds like a duck, walks like a duck, then it's a duck". Kind of thing.

So effectively I would like to be able to NOT worry about distinguishing "element" object being a textbox or span in my widget. Instead wrap it into a generic wrapper.

However people have advised me that in javascript widgets the usual convention is to take care of component specific stuff within widgets. I am not convinced, as I firmly believe in programming to interfaces and not specifics. So I am at conflict.

In my example above, I don't think so the highlighted dilemma does justice to this problem, but on a larger scale this pops up as a question for me often.

I would like to hear opinion from guys, as to how to build that component independence within my widget for an HTML DOM? Is a solution to create javascript wrapper objects with same interface and then css-select them separately and then make method call as following?

```
(function() {
    var locateAllComponents = function() {
         $(".generic-class").each(function(index, element) {
             //wrap element into suitable wrapper that has common interface for getter
             //setter.
             GloballyDefinedNamespace.StringUtils.convert(wrappedElement);
         });
    };

}())
```

Any insights and answers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to force concepts on javascript that are foreign to it.

Programming to an interface works for for OOP, but for other language types it is a bad idea.

You can look at how jquery uses .text() (http://api.jquery.com/text/) and .val() (http://api.jquery.com/val/) and you will see that what you want to abstract they put into two different functions, for a reason.

Widgets can be useful, but at a cost of bloat and performance, so you need to look at what you are doing and ensure that you don't exact too much of a price.

So, start small, perhaps with a widget that can work on form elements, and see what you can do reasonably within the object, but you will find that at some point it becomes very helpful if either the API user or the API developer creates functions to pass in to your widget, to get the additional functionality.

But, all of this will impact performance, so as you work, do some unit tests so you can look at changes in performance to help guide you on what changes are worth the price.

You may want to start with looking at the JQuery UI widgets though, and see what they did, rather than just re-inventing the wheel for no reason.